# Django form re-validation for null/blank fields

Tags: python, django

I have a model and two fields and either fields are set to accept null and blank values. Now I want my modelForm to be posted only when one of them fields is validated or filled. I already have an answer with jquery but i wanted to know if its possible with django.

Heres my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="static/pic", blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I think you need to set null=False if you want to validate using ModelForm

Comment: But if I do so, I can't update the field with null value..For eg: One user might want to only update content and ignore the image field, while another user might want to do the exact opposite..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the clean method in modelform like this:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['image'] is not None or self.cleaned_data['content'] != '' :
          return super().clean() #For python 3
          #return super(YourForm, self).clean() // for python 2
    raise ValidationError('Some Error')
```